# How do Cell Modems know the tower Type they are connected to?

Tags: mobile

I hope this is the right place to ask this question but can someone tell me how a cell modem with network fallback/forward knows what network it is connected too?  Is there typically an AT-Command that is issued that returns network information or is that determined based on what is going out of the modem?  Like how data is 4G LTE but voice communication falls back to 1xRTT for CDMA modems.

I'm looking at a Modem with this fallback/forward functionality and for debugging purposes would like to know if it is on a 3G connection or 4G.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

3G and 4G are incompatible from a physical layer perspective. The modem knows whether the network is 3G or 4G because it knows what PHY protocol it is using.